# how to show/hide divs in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to click on `xxxx` show content of `<div id="list-name" class="list-item">` and click on `xxx1x` .........

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $("#list-groupname").click(function() {
      $("#list-name").toggle();
    });
  });



div.list-group-item {
  display: none !important;
  opacity: 0;
}

.showitems {
  display: block;
}

#list-filtername {
  display: block;
}



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group">
  <a id="list-groupname" class="list-item">xxxx</a>
    <div id="list-name" class="list-item">
      <div id="name-group2000020">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" name="x" value="z1" checked="checked" />Checkbox
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<a id="list-groupname" class="list-item">xxx1x</a>
  <div id="list-name" class="list-item">
    <div id="name-group2000021">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="x" value="z1" checked="checked" />Checkbox1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

click xxxx show but xxxx1x not show. i AM SORRY, BEGINNER

no success

Comment: The css rule `div.list-group-item` does not appear to match any of the markup, but it's contents are doing an !important on the display none which would override inline styling of the display property.  Also the toggle on an element wouldn't change the opacity at all.

Comment: @talpar?help? i dont know jquery

Comment: Taplar's talking about CSS not jquery. I added the jQuery library file to your snippet above and now it seems to show and hide successfully when the `<a>` is clicked. From the description, that seems to be what you wanted, or is there something else?

Comment: @ADyson . this example for bigger code,when click xxxx only div 1 hide but other div ha not show.

Comment: What other div? We can't read your mind, what other div are you trying to show? There's only one in the question which contains any content. Please clarify your intention and give an example which can actually reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, don't use `<a> anchor tag` if you're not making use of hyperlinks, you can make `use of span or div instead`.
- If you want to initally set the content to hide, just set the CSS of the `list-name` to *display:none*.
- `Don't make use of the same ID` in more than one container.
- Remove class `"list-item"` from anchor  tag.

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $(".list-groupname").click(function() {
      $(this).next(".list-item").toggle();
    });
  });
```

```css
.list-item{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group">
  <span class="list-groupname">xxxx</span>
    <div id="list-name1" class="list-item">
      <div id="name-group2000020">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" name="x" value="z1" checked="checked" />Checkbox
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<span class="list-groupname">xxx1x</span>
  <div id="list-name2" class="list-item">
    <div id="name-group2000021">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="x" value="z1" checked="checked" />Checkbox1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: EDITS CODES FOR U

Comment: @Katty1995 Updated.

Comment: class in <a and <div same and not change this class. not work for me.

Comment: You cannot have the same classnames for both since youre clicking one and trying to hide the next.

Answer (score 0):

Use `toggleClass` with your class name `list-group-item`, is this what you need, if not please leave a comment and I would be more than happy to help and edit my answer!

```js
    $(document).ready(
        function() {
            $("#list-groupname").click(function() {
                $("#list-name").toggleClass("list-group-item");
            });
        });
```

```css
    div.list-group-item {
      display: none !important;
      opacity: 0 ;
    }
    
    .showitems {
      display: block;
    
    }
    #list-filtername {
      display: block;
    
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group">
            <a id="list-groupname" class="list-item">xxxx</a>
        <div id="list-name" class="list-item">
          <div id="name-group2000020">
                    <div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="x" value="z1" checked="checked" />
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying you want it to show the checkbox when you click it, just use .show() instead of .toggle() and set its initial display property to none. With your code, it appeared to work for toggling the checkbox if that's what you were trying to do.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#list-groupname").click(function() {
    $("#list-name").show()
 });
});
```

```css
div.list-group-item {
      display: none !important;
      opacity: 0 ;
    }
    
    .showitems {
      display: block;
    
    }
    #list-filtername {
      display: block;
    
    }

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group">
            <a id="list-groupname" class="list-item">xxxx</a>
        <div id="list-name" class="list-item">
          <div id="name-group2000020">
                    <div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="x" value="z1" checked="checked" />
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group">
            <a id="list-groupname" class="list-item">xxxx</a>
        <div id="list-name" class="list-item" style = "display: none;">
          <div id="name-group2000020">
                    <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="x" value="z1" checked="checked" />
                    </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```